# Linking unrelated collections in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have an app that displays Artist and Venue records created my a specific user on their user profile page, and also displays user comments (and usernames) under these records.  This code is working correctly.

However, under the Artist record, I would also like to display all the VENUES, so the artist can select (i.e. tag) which venues they have played at.  Likewise, the venues can tag which artists have played at the venue.

The difference with the current user model is that the user is DIRECTLY LINKED to the artist/venue record, as they created them.  The artists and venues on the other hand are not currently linked at all, so I'm struggling with how to link them together.  I suspect the problem is related to how I've defined venues in my Artist Mongoose schema, but I'm still pretty new to this so seeking some guidance.  The error message I am getting is 'venue is undefined'.

Artist Schema:

```
 // SCHEMA SETUP - Artist
    var artistSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
       name: String,
       logo: String,
       shortDescription: String,
       createdAt:{
            type:Date,
            default:Date.now
       },
       author: {
          id: {
             type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
             ref: "User" //references user model
          },
          username: String
       },
       comments: [
          {
             type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
             ref: "Comment"
          }   
       ],
       venue: {
           id: {
             type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
             ref: "Venue"     
           },
           name: String 
       }

    });

    var Artist = mongoose.model("Artist", artistSchema);
```

Venue Schema:

```
// SCHEMA SETUP - Venue
var venueSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
   name: String,
   logo: String,
   address: String,
   contact: String,
   createdAt:{
        type:Date,
        default:Date.now
   },
   author: {
      id: {
         type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
         ref: "User" //references user model
      },
      username: String
   }
});
```

Show artist route:

```
// SHOW - shows more info about one artist
app.get("/artist/:id", function(req, res){
    //find the artist with provided ID
    Artist.findById(req.params.id).populate("comments").exec(function(err, foundArtist){
        Venue.find().exec(function (err, venues) {
            if(err){
                console.log(err);
            } else {
                //render show template with that artist
                res.render("show", {artist: foundArtist});
            }
        });
    });
})
```

Code to display venues on artist page (show.ejs):

```
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <% venues.forEach(function(venue) { %>
                <li><a href="/venue/<%=artist.venue.id %>"><%= artist.venue.name %></a></li>
            <% }); %>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Akshay this is my other related question in case you're able to offer any guidance!  Many thanks! :)

Comment: Hi, any further information I could add here to supplement the requirement? Thanks